Doesn't work RCE after installing Canvas LMS
I've followed the PRODUCTION installation manual from this Instructure’s Github link - and have been able to successfully install Canvas.
The setup is 3 part systems: Canvas node, Postgres database (managed services on AWS), and Redis (managed services on AWS).
Everything works as expected, except the RCE (Rich-Content-Editor) module. The RCE installation is described Here, but after following the instructions, we are unable to use RCE API server.
The long and short of this issue is that the RCE API server is unable to authenticate the user requests made to all API endpoints handled by this server.
What's the solution?
